# Rails routing link to specific show

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, routes

This question seems a little basic, but considering I have 'pages#show' with a show page with url 'history'. How could I add this specific show page to a link:

```
= link_to 'History', pages_path(@?????)
```

**PD1:** I would prefer avoid using `:id` since I tend to seed a lot of data, and per `db:seed` all id's tend to change.

**PD2:** I know I can achieve this creating an action and then setting it on router.rb. But in long time that's a great deal of time consumption.

Comment: I am a bit confused! you want to add the History link to a page that when user clicks on it go to a page which is about "History", correct? Why not using `Permalink` instead of `id`. It doesn't change and you are not relying on the id. If you let me know this is what you think might work I can put some code down for you. cheers.

Comment: Hi Mr H. That's what I need, please share the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
rails generate migration AddPermalinkToPages permalink:string
```

After you added then you need to create the permalink on the fly when you are saving the page or updating it. I usually do it in the model so I keep the controller clean. You can define it in a PagesHelper if you want user to assign the permalink and call in in the view. It really depends on how you want to interact with user.

Anyway, ( if you want to define it in Model then )

```
  def self.make_slug(aString)
    aString.downcase.gsub(/[^a-z1-9]+/, '-').chomp('-')
  end
```

In your page.rb

```
  def to_param
    permalink
  end
```

In your pages_controller.rb ( if you need to) - here id will be the permalink so your user will be something like this /history/a-page-slug

```
  private
  ## Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
  def set_page
    @page = Page.find_by_permalink(params[:id])
  end
```

Don't need to do anything with your route.

Please let me know if you need more help.

Cheers

Comment: Actually, I'm using friendly id already. But your approach helped me to get the answer needed. Thanks. I had to set the find method inside application_controller in order to make the link visible in all pages.

Comment: Cool. Glad it could help. I always use Gem only if I have to. It is easier to maintain the code dependencies. Good Luck.